# Convert DELF features to CSV format

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have duplicated duplicating results of research paper "Large-Scale Image Retrieval with Attentive Deep Local Features", and successfully extracted deep local features. 
But these features are extracted and saved with .delf extension, which is not readable.
I have tried and converted them to .csv fomat, but still they are not in readable form.
I want to store DELF features in .csv format, so that I can combine them and use for classification purpose?

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific, how did you get these .delf files? what code generated them?

Comment: Used this link for processing of .delf files https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/delf

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/EXTRACTION_MATCHING.md This is sublink of previous link and command mentioned "python extract_features.py \
  --config_path delf_config_example.pbtxt \
  --list_images_path list_images.txt \
  --output_dir data/oxford5k_features
" has created image1.delf, image2.delf and so on.

Comment: add information by editing your quesiton. not via comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're like 3 mouse clicks away from the answer.

A quick look into the linked Github respository gives you the following file:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/delf/python/feature_io.py

which implements both reading and writing .delf files. It pretty much boils down to (de)serialization of a few numpy arrays.

features -> numpy arrays -> string -> file

and vice versa:

file -> string -> numpy arrays -> features

Comment: I have reached to feature_io.py file, but could you please clarify the things? Should I convert created .delf files to csv through numpy? or make changes in feature_io.py?

Comment: @MuhammadHanif this code shows you how the data is structured and stored. so whatever you want to do with that data you can do. I don't understand your problem herer

Comment: Thankyou Piglet! I have solved the problem by your help. By just using these few lines of code: [ from delf import feature_io ] [filename='/home/hanif/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/models/research/delf/delf/python/examples/data/oxford5k_features/image1.delf] [data_read = feature_io.ReadFromFile(filename)] 'data_read'